# Write multidimensional vectors (tensors) of scalars to file in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, save

#### The description of the object I have

I have several N-dimensional containers in my code, representing tensors, whose types are defined as

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<...<double>...>>>
```

These type of data structures occur in several different sizes and dimensions and they only contain scalar numbers. The number of dimensions is known for every vector and can be accessed as eg. `tensor::dimension`. Since they're representing tensors, they're never "irregular": at the bottom level, vectors always contain the same number of elements, like this:

```
// THIS IS HOW THEY ALWAYS LOOK LIKE
T tensor = {{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}}

// THIS IS WHAT NEVER HAPPENS
T tensor = {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2}}
```

#### What I want to do with this object

I want to save each of these multidimensional vectors (tensors basically) into different files, which I can then easily load/read eg. in Python into a `numpy.array` - for further analysis and visualization. How can I achieve this to save any of these N-dimensional `std::vector`s in **modern C++** without explicitly defining a basic write-to-txt function with N nested loops for each vector with different dimensions?

(Note: Solutions/advice that require/mention only standard libraries are preferred, but I'm happy to hear any other answers too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to iterate over something in C++ is a loop, in some sort of shape, matter, or form. So no matter what you're going to have loops. There are no workarounds or alternatives, but it doesn't mean you actually have to write all these loops yourself, one at a time. This is why we have templates in C++. What you are looking for is a recursive template, that recursively peels away each dimension: until the last one which gets implemented for real-sies, basically letting your compiler write every loop for you. Mission accomplished. Starting with a simplistic example of writing out a plain vector

```
void write_vec(const std::vector<double> &v)
{
   for (const auto &value:vector)
       std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

The actual details of how you want to save each value, and which files, is irrelevant here, you can adjust the above code to make it work in whichever way you see fit.  The point that you want to make it work for some artbirary dimensions. Simply add a template with the same name, then let overload resolution do all the work for you:

```
template<typename T>
void write_vec(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &v)
{
   for (const auto &value:vector)
       write_vec(value);
}
```

Now, a `write_vec(anything)`, where *anything* is any `N`-"deep" vector that ends up in a `std::vector<double>` will walk its way downhill, on its own, and write out every `double`.